# Best way to encode text data for XML in Java?

Tags: java, xml, encoding

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157646/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml), except for Java.

What is the recommended way of encoding strings for an XML output in Java. The strings might contain characters like "&", "<", etc.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Very simply: use an XML library. That way it will actually be *right* instead of requiring detailed knowledge of bits of the XML spec.

Comment: Can you recommend such a library?  (I find it surprising that this is not a standard part of Java edition 5...such a common task).

Comment: XML *is* part of the standard Java framework - look in org.w3c.sax and org.w3c.dom. However, there are some easier-to-use framework around as well, such as JDom. Note that there may not be an "encoding strings for XML output" method - I was more recommending that the whole XML task should be done with a library rather than just doing bits at a time with string manipulation.

Comment: This is not such useful advice when outputting XHTML - FlyingSaucer requires XML, but there ain't no way I'm templating through an XML lib :).  Thankfully StringTemplate allows me to quickly escape all String objects.

Comment: @Stephen: I would expect an XHTML library to use an XML library to keep everything sane, but expose an XHTML-centric API. Having to do escaping manually (and make sure you get it right *everywhere*) is not a great idea IMO.

Comment: To convert a DOM tree to an XML-string, use a transformer without a style sheet.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "Very simply". Some platforms don't have xml generation library, yet you may need to encode some text into xml. Adding few hundreds KB of lib just due to this task is not simple, and not wanted. I wouln't accept this answer.

Comment: @mice: The question is tagged Java, and Java has *lots* of XML libraries. Indeed, there are XML APIs baked into Java, so there'd be no need to add *anything* else... but even if you did, a few hundred K is rarely a problem outside mobile these days. Even if it weren't Java, I'd be very wary of developing on a platform which didn't have any XML APIs...

Comment: I'm considering Android. It uses Java, and Apps have to be small. It has xml parsers, but I'm not aware of opposite (is it called "xml serializer"?).

Comment: @mice: The DOM API is perfectly capable of generating XML. Or there are fairly small third-party libraries. (JDom's jar file is 114K for example.) **Using an XML API is still the recommended way of creating XML.**

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439298/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml-in-java/10035382#10035382 for simple purpose of escaping xml text (not building xml).

Comment: @mice: I think I've made my position pretty clear. If I want to do anything with XML, I'll use an XML API. That's what they're good at. In my experience it's pretty rare to need to escape XML when you're not *building* XML. I'm not going to comment on the suitability of some code I wouldn't use in principle. (EDIT: Actually, I will in this case. I'll comment directly.)

Comment: No problem with your approach. However I use such code, which creates xml by String.printf and filling in some text in pre-constructed xml string. You may use xml lib, I can't in my specific case.

Comment: @mice: It sounds like you may have picked a bad tool to start with then. Any library which is creating XML for me and inserting bits of text into it should be doing the escaping itself. It's not easy getting the full picture of what your specific requirements are in comments, but I certainly stand by my answer.

Comment: Just a general observation seeing that the word "right" is emphasized: By just using any XML library it doesn't guarantee that it will be right ;-). Library developers are also human. Of course you'b be pretty safe with standard stuff or something like Apache Commons Lang... just ever so often amazed by how people just trust other people's code blindly...

Comment: @JonSkeet I am converting csv file to xml just using Java (no groovy). What kind of XML libraries are out there for such conversion? Thanks!

Comment: @Learner: There are loads. You might want to start with jdom.

Comment: We are using the woodstox stax library and it does not have a way of writing text where it will encode the special characters. It has the call writeCharacters but it doesn't encode > (does encode <).

Comment: @DavidThielen That doesn't need to be encoded. It often is, but IIRC the XML spec calls it out as being okay not to be encoded.

Comment: Be carefully! XML and therefore also the DOM API only supports characters in the ranges #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]. If you want to use characters outside of this ranges you have to escape them with an own escaping system additionally. You can use my methods here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59475093/3882565.

Comment: @stonar96 Yes, I've been assuming that a valid XML document is the desired result. If you need to express things that can't be expressed in XML, that's a bigger problem. It's a shame that XML 1.1 never really took off, as that fixes this problem.

Comment: Sorry man, I downvoted it and was wrong. Now cannot change it back. This answer is correct

Comment: @Alexandr: Really not a problem :)

Answer (score 130):

As others have mentioned, using an XML library is the easiest way. If you do want to escape yourself, you could look into [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) from the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library.

Comment: This could be the way to go if you don't care about absolute correctness, for example if you are putting together a prototype.

Comment: Use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(str)` from [`commons-lang`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). I use it in App Engine application - work like a charm. Here is the [Java Doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) for this function:

Comment: The escapeXml method of StringEscapeUtils seems to be a bit costly. Is there a more efficient method that operates on a StringBuffer instead of a String?

Comment: Do this method work for both XML content and attributes? To me it seems like it doesn't work for attributes. It doesn't seem to escape `\t`, `\n` and `\r`.

Comment: @Lii and `\t`, `\n` or `\r` needs to be escaped ?

Comment: Note that `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()` does not escape control characters, which are invalid in XML in many situations

Comment: Note that it has been moved from `commons-lang` to `commons-text`

Answer (score 21):

Just use.

```
<![CDATA[ your text here ]]>
```

This will allow any characters except the ending

```
]]>
```

So you can include characters that would be illegal such as & and >. For example.

```
<element><![CDATA[ characters such as & and > are allowed ]]></element>
```

However, attributes will need to be escaped as CDATA blocks can not be used for them.

Comment: In most cases, that is not what you should do.  Too many people abuse the CDATA tags.  The intent of the CDATA is to tell the processor not to process it as XML and just pass it through.  If you are trying to create an XML file, then you should be creating XML, not just passing bytes through some wrapping element.

Comment: @Mads, using CDATA results in a valid XML file so it is just as fine as doing it the "right way".  If you dislike it, then parse it afterwards, identity transform it, and print it.

Comment: If you wrap text in a CDATA element you have to escape the CDATA closing marker: "]]>"... except you cannot escape that. So instead you have to break your code into pieces where you put half of the data in one CDATA element and the other half in a second: <![CDATA[This data contain a CDATA closing marker: "]]]]><![CDATA[>" that is why it had to be split up.]]>   ... In the end it may be a lot simpler to just escape '<', '>' and '&' instead. Of course many apps ignore the potential problem with CDATA closing markers in the data. Ignorance is bliss I guess. :)

Comment: @StijndeWitt is absolutely correct. CDATA is not a panacea for escaping special characters.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  CDATA does not allow any character outside of the XML's encoding.

Comment: In XML file (Java and DOM Parser), "&lt;" is present as node text value but when node.getContentType is used for this node then this is converted to "<". Is there anyway to retrieve "&lt;" itself, instead of  "<"?

Answer (score 18):

This question is eight years old and still not a fully correct answer! No, you should not have to import an entire third party API to do this simple task. Bad advice.

The following method will:

- correctly handle characters outside the basic multilingual plane
- escape characters required in XML
- escape any non-ASCII characters, which is optional but common
- replace *illegal* characters in XML 1.0 with the Unicode substitution character. There is no best option here - removing them is just as valid.

I've tried to optimise for the most common case, while still ensuring you could pipe /dev/random through this and get a valid string in XML.

```
public static String encodeXML(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int len = s.length();
    for (int i=0;i<len;) {
        int c = s.codePointAt(i);
        if (c < 0x80) {      // ASCII range: test most common case first
            if (c < 0x20 && (c != '\t' && c != '\r' && c != '\n')) {
                // Illegal XML character, even encoded. Skip or substitute
                sb.append("&#xfffd;");   // Unicode replacement character
            } else {
                switch(c) {
                  case '&':  sb.append("&amp;"); break;
                  case '>':  sb.append("&gt;"); break;
                  case '<':  sb.append("&lt;"); break;
                  // Uncomment next two if encoding for an XML attribute
//                  case '\''  sb.append("&apos;"); break;
//                  case '\"'  sb.append("&quot;"); break;
                  // Uncomment next three if you prefer, but not required
//                  case '\n'  sb.append("&#10;"); break;
//                  case '\r'  sb.append("&#13;"); break;
//                  case '\t'  sb.append("&#9;"); break;

                  default:   sb.append((char)c);
                }
            }
        } else if ((c >= 0xd800 && c <= 0xdfff) || c == 0xfffe || c == 0xffff) {
            // Illegal XML character, even encoded. Skip or substitute
            sb.append("&#xfffd;");   // Unicode replacement character
        } else {
            sb.append("&#x");
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(c));
            sb.append(';');
        }
        i += c <= 0xffff ? 1 : 2;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

*Edit: for those who continue to insist it foolish to write your own code for this when there are perfectly good Java APIs to deal with XML, you might like to know that the StAX API included with Oracle Java 8 (I haven't tested others) fails to encode CDATA content correctly: it doesn't escape ]]> sequences in the content. A third party library, even one that's part of the Java core, is not always the best option.*

Comment: +1 for standalone code. Just comparing your code with [guava implementation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/xml/XmlEscapers.html#line.75), I'm wondering what about '\t','\n','\r' ? See also notes at [guava docs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/xml/XmlEscapers.html#xmlContentEscaper--)

Comment: There's no need to escape \n, \r and \t, they are valid, although they do make formatting a bit ugly. I've modified the code to show how to escsape them if that's what you want.

Comment: There is *no* way to "escape ]]>" in CDATA.

Comment: Then it should reject the content by throwing an IllegalArgumentException. Under no circumstances should it claim to succeed but still output invalid XML.

Comment: Instead of replacing illegal characters in XML 1.0 with the Unicode substitution character you can use my methods here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59475093/3882565.

Comment: Useful and appreciated! Nevertheless hard to read code.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
String xmlEscapeText(String t) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++){
      char c = t.charAt(i);
      switch(c){
      case '<': sb.append("&lt;"); break;
      case '>': sb.append("&gt;"); break;
      case '\"': sb.append("&quot;"); break;
      case '&': sb.append("&amp;"); break;
      case '\'': sb.append("&apos;"); break;
      default:
         if(c>0x7e) {
            sb.append("&#"+((int)c)+";");
         }else
            sb.append(c);
      }
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: You've got at least two bugs that I can see. One is subtle, the other isn't. I wouldn't have such a bug - because I wouldn't reinvent the wheel in the first place.

Comment: And iterating through Unicode strings is a bit more complicated. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1527856/402322

Comment: I assume the non-subtle bug is the "guot" which was corrected - I also get a warning on the appending concatenated strings in the StringBuilder.  What is the subtle bug?  I honestly like a stand-alone solution like this for my current implementation, embedded where we can't import apache libraries.

Comment: Not sure it is _subtle_ but It'd better consider the case where `t==null`.

Comment: As a comparison, 
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml
supports only the five basic XML entities (gt, lt, quot, amp, apos).
Note that Unicode characters greater than 0x7f are no longer escaped. ([source](http://bit.ly/19FpMvH))

Comment: Shouldn't your default case's if condition read "if (c<32 || c>0x7e) {"? Otherwise, you are encoding all characters less than space as just themselves which is invalid XML content, right?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium: expected chars <32 are only new-lines or tabs, and these are not escaped.

Comment: @PointerNull Are you sure about that?! I've read MANY other places that those are to be escaped, too. Do you have an official reference you can cite which explicitly states they are not to be escaped? If so, I'd really appreciate it (and perhaps it would begin to stem the vast number of suggestions to encode this space).

Comment: @PointerNull Ok, It's an old thing to mention now, but a lot of the non-printable Unicode characters that map to ASCII for compatibility are going to be passed along with this routine.  I'm thinking of things like embedded null values `0x00`, embedded "start of text" `0x02`, "end of transmission" `0x04`, and so on.  Certainly not to be expected in your typical Java string, but it's funny how such things get slipped in.

Comment: This is a terrible solution, anyone reading do not use this.  This will convert "&amp;" into "&ampamp;" and whatnot.  .

Comment: @user1003916: XML escaping is designed to convert any & occurrence into &amp; so that's how it has to work. If you excape already escaped string, that's your fault.

Comment: I'm happy with the final version. Java SE is compact, fast, and efficient. Doing just what needs to be done rather than downloading another 100 MB of bloatware is always better in my book.

Comment: All characters below 0x20  except 0x09, 0x0A and 0x0D are invalid in XML. This applies whether they are escaped or not. The only correct way to handle those is to skip them or throw an Exception. Other than that, this is a good solution and similar to the one we'd typically use.

Comment: @ceving You don't have to deal with Unicode here as all characters outside the BMP can be simply copied as they are. The only five codepoints needing processing are in the BMP.

Comment: For a method which also supports invalid XML characters like ```'\u0000'``` see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59475093/3882565.

Comment: The question was "what is the recommended way".  Writing your own method for a common task isn't.

Answer (score 9):

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()` does not escape control characters (< 0x20).  XML 1.1 allows control characters; XML 1.0 does not.  For example, `XStream.toXML()` will happily serialize a Java object's control characters into XML, which an XML 1.0 parser will reject.

To escape control characters with Apache commons-lang, use

```
NumericEntityEscaper.below(0x20).translate(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(str))
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public String escapeXml(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;").replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll("\"", "&quot;").replaceAll("'", "&apos;");
}
```

Comment: Chaining `replaceAll` calls is very inefficient, especially for large strings.  Every call results in a new String object being created, which will hang around until garbage collected.  Also, each call requires looping through the string again.  This could be consolidated into one single manual loop with comparisons against each target char in every iteration.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, even if it is inefficient. It solves the problem in a single line.

Comment: And it has many bugs. See [this comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439298/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml-in-java#comment68579952_10035382)

Comment: To fix these bugs you can additionally use my method here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59475093/3882565. Note that this is not a replacement but it can be used additionally.

Answer (score 8):

For those looking for the quickest-to-write solution: use methods from [apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

- [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml10(java.lang.String)) for xml 1.0
- [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml11(java.lang.String)) for xml 1.1
- [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.lang.String)) is now deprecated, but was used commonly in the past

Remember to include dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.5</version> <!--check current version! -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Note that it has been moved from commons-lang to commons-text

Answer (score 6):

While idealism says use an XML library, IMHO if you have a basic idea of XML then common sense and performance says template it all the way. It's arguably more readable too. Though using the escaping routines of a library is probably a good idea.

Consider this: XML *was* meant to be written by humans.

Use libraries for generating XML when having your XML as an "object" better models your problem. For example, if pluggable modules participate in the process of building this XML.

Edit: as for how to actually escape XML in templates, use of CDATA or `escapeXml(string)` from JSTL are two good solutions, `escapeXml(string)` can be used like this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

<item>${fn:escapeXml(value)}</item>
```

Answer (score 6):

The behavior of StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml() has changed from Commons Lang 2.5 to 3.0.
It now no longer escapes Unicode characters greater than 0x7f.

This is a good thing, the old method was to be a bit to eager to escape entities that could just be inserted into a utf8 document.

The new escapers to be included in Google Guava 11.0 also seem promising:
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=799

Comment: Here's Guava's XML escaper: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/xml/XmlEscapers.java?r=8124eb561b979c5d4300f5694f8871d1d7a5619e. In general, I've found Guava to be better architected than Apache Commons.

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/xml/XmlEscapers.html

Answer (score 6):

While I agree with Jon Skeet in principle, sometimes I don't have the option to use an external XML library. And I find it peculiar the two functions to escape/unescape a simple value (attribute or tag, not full document) are not available in the standard XML libraries included with Java.

As a result and based on the different answers I have seen posted here and elsewhere, here is the solution I've ended up creating (nothing worked as a simple copy/paste):

```
  public final static String ESCAPE_CHARS = "<>&\"\'";
  public final static List<String> ESCAPE_STRINGS = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(new String[] {
      "&lt;"
    , "&gt;"
    , "&amp;"
    , "&quot;"
    , "&apos;"
  }));

  private static String UNICODE_NULL = "" + ((char)0x00); //null
  private static String UNICODE_LOW =  "" + ((char)0x20); //space
  private static String UNICODE_HIGH = "" + ((char)0x7f);

  //should only be used for the content of an attribute or tag      
  public static String toEscaped(String content) {
    String result = content;
    
    if ((content != null) && (content.length() > 0)) {
      boolean modified = false;
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(content.length());
      for (int i = 0, count = content.length(); i < count; ++i) {
        String character = content.substring(i, i + 1);
        int pos = ESCAPE_CHARS.indexOf(character);
        if (pos > -1) {
          stringBuilder.append(ESCAPE_STRINGS.get(pos));
          modified = true;
        }
        else {
          if (    (character.compareTo(UNICODE_LOW) > -1)
               && (character.compareTo(UNICODE_HIGH) < 1)
             ) {
            stringBuilder.append(character);
          }
          else {
            //Per URL reference below, Unicode null character is always restricted from XML
            //URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML
            if (character.compareTo(UNICODE_NULL) != 0) {
              stringBuilder.append("&#" + ((int)character.charAt(0)) + ";");
            }
            modified = true;
          }
        }
      }
      if (modified) {
        result = stringBuilder.toString();
      }
    }
    
    return result;
  }
```

The above accommodates several different things:

1. avoids using char based logic until it absolutely has to - improves unicode compatibility
2. attempts to be as efficient as possible given the probability is the second "if" condition is likely the most used pathway
3. is a pure function; i.e. is thread-safe
4. optimizes nicely with the garbage collector by only returning the contents of the StringBuilder if something actually changed - otherwise, the original string is returned

At some point, I will write the inversion of this function, toUnescaped(). I just don't have time to do that today. When I do, I will come update this answer with the code. :)

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. I do not wish to add another jar to my project for only one method. If you please grant permission, may I copy paste your code in mine?

Comment: @SatishMotwani Of course you can take the above code and do with it as you like. It's my understanding that any code published on StackOverflow is assumed to be copyright free (isn't covered as a work in totality). On the flip side, it would be exceedingly difficult for someone to press any sort of copyright claim and expect an sort of outcome for themselves.

Comment: You forgot to handle NUL characters. And maybe other things too.

Comment: @DavidBalažic Okay, please explain in more detail what I might have missed it? Please read through the code more closely. I handled EVERY SINGLE Unicode character (of the 1,111,998), including the `null` character. Can you explain the definition of the two values, `UNICODE_LOW` and `UNICODE_HIGH`? Please reread the `if` that uses those two values. Notice `null` (`\u0000` which is `(int)0`) doesn't fall between these two values. Read out how it becomes properly "escaped" just like ALL Unicode characters existing outside the `UNICODE_LOW` and `UNICODE_HIGH` range, by using the `&#` technique.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium NULL is illegal in XML (and some other characters too). Doesn't matter how you encode it. It is illegal. (also: there is really no need to escape Unicode characters, they are nicely supported in XML, except if the XML document has a non-Unicode encoding itself)

Comment: @DavidBalažic Ah. Tysvm for your explanation. I found a reference document that explicitly identifies what you are asserting about Unicode `null`. However, that is literally the ONLY character not allowed. There are many which are strongly discouraged, but NUL is the only one explicitly unreservedly restricted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML

Comment: @DavidBalažic I have updated the answer to now incorporate the restriction cited in the reference I shared in my last comment. I added a comment and logic to correctly handle this case. Again, tysvm for your precise feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Note: Your question is about *escaping*, not *encoding*. Escaping is using <, etc. to allow the parser to distinguish between "this is an XML command" and "this is some text". Encoding is the stuff you specify in the XML header (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, etc).

First of all, like everyone else said, use an XML library. XML looks simple but the encoding+escaping stuff is dark voodoo (which you'll notice as soon as you encounter umlauts and Japanese and other weird stuff like "[full width digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1c0s6bb.aspx)" (&#FF11; is 1)). Keeping XML human readable is a Sisyphus' task.

I suggest never to try to be clever about text encoding and escaping in XML. But don't let that stop you from trying; just remember when it bites you (and it will).

That said, if you use only UTF-8, to make things more readable you can consider this strategy:

- If the text does contain '<', '>' or '&', wrap it in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`
- If the text doesn't contain these three characters, don't warp it.

I'm using this in an SQL editor and it allows the developers to cut&paste SQL from a third party SQL tool into the XML without worrying about escaping. This works because the SQL can't contain umlauts in our case, so I'm safe.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a library to get the job done, try:

1. [Guava 26.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/26.0-jre) documented [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/xml/XmlEscapers.html#xmlContentEscaper)

   `return XmlEscapers.xmlContentEscaper().escape(text);`

   > Note: There is also an `xmlAttributeEscaper()`
2. [Apache Commons Text 1.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.4) documented [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml11-java.lang.String-)

   `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(text)`

   > Note: There is also an `escapeXml10()` method

Answer (score 3):

To escape XML characters, the easiest way is to use the Apache Commons Lang project, JAR downloadable from: http://commons.apache.org/lang/

The class is this: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

It has a method named "escapeXml", that will return an appropriately escaped String.

Comment: Update: escapeXml is now deprecated - use escapeXml10. Ref https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Enterprise Security API (ESAPI) library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.esapi/esapi), which provides methods like `encodeForXML` and `encodeForXMLAttribute`. Take a look at the documentation of the [Encoder](https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html) interface; it also contains examples of how to create an instance of [DefaultEncoder](https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultEncoder.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [JAXP](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXP) and forget about text handling it will be done for you automatically.

Comment: Your link is in Spanish, which is not so helpful for the most of us. Better is [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXP).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy solution and it's great for encoding accented characters too!

```
String in = "Hi Lârry & Môe!";

StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
    char c = in.charAt(i);
    if(c < 31 || c > 126 || "<>\"'\\&".indexOf(c) >= 0) {
        out.append("&#" + (int) c + ";");
    } else {
        out.append(c);
    }
}

System.out.printf("%s%n", out);
```

Outputs

```
Hi L&#226;rry &#38; M&#244;e!
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "31" in the first line of the "if" be "32"; i.e. less than the space character? And if "31" must remain, then shouldn't it be corrected to read "if (c <= 31 ||..." (additional equals sign following the less than sign)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the XML using Apache XML serializer

```
//Serialize DOM
OutputFormat format    = new OutputFormat (doc); 
// as a String
StringWriter stringOut = new StringWriter ();    
XMLSerializer serial   = new XMLSerializer (stringOut, 
                                          format);
serial.serialize(doc);
// Display the XML
System.out.println(stringOut.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
 & with &amp;
```

And for other characters:

```
> with &gt;
< with &lt;
\" with &quot;
' with &apos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found after searching everywhere looking for a solution:

Get the Jsoup library:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.nodes.Entities
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser

String xml = '''<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

   <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:m = "http://www.example.org/quotations">
      <m:GetQuotation>
         <m:QuotationsName> MiscroSoft@G>>gle.com </m:QuotationsName>
      </m:GetQuotation>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'''



Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser())
doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8")
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.base)

println doc.toString()
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score -1):

> I have created my wrapper here, hope it will helps a lot, [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51833809/7346931) You can modify depends on your requirements