# How can I iterate through the unicode codepoints of a Java String?

Tags: java, string, unicode

So I know about [`String#codePointAt(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)), but it's indexed by the `char` offset, not by the codepoint offset.

I'm thinking about trying something like:

- using [`String#charAt(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) to get the `char` at an index
- testing whether the `char` is in the [high-surrogates range](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode)

  - if so, use [`String#codePointAt(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)) to get the codepoint, and increment the index by 2
  - if not, use the given `char` value as the codepoint,  and increment the index by 1

But my concerns are

- I'm not sure whether codepoints which are naturally in the high-surrogates range will be stored as two `char` values or one
- this seems like an awful expensive way to iterate through characters
- someone must have come up with something better.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Yes, Java uses a UTF-16-esque encoding for internal representations of Strings, and, yes, it encodes characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane ([BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)) using the surrogacy scheme.

If you know you'll be dealing with characters outside the BMP, then here is the canonical way to iterate over the characters of a Java String:

```
final int length = s.length();
for (int offset = 0; offset < length; ) {
   final int codepoint = s.codePointAt(offset);

   // do something with the codepoint

   offset += Character.charCount(codepoint);
}
```

Comment: As for whether or not it's "expensive", well... there is no other way built into Java. But if you're dealing only with Latin/European/Cyrillic/Greek/Hebrew/Arabic scripts, then you just s.charAt() to your heart's content. :)

Comment: But you shouldn't. For instance if your program outputs XML and if someone gives it some obscure mathematical operator, suddenly your XML may be invalid.

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg That's what I thought. But here came that special mathematical E. UTF-16 works 99% of the time — but then it get really painful. Especially when the problems stay hidden for a long time.

Comment: I would have used `offset = s.offsetByCodePoints(offset, 1);`. Is there some benefit in using `offset += Character.charCount(codepoint);` instead?

Comment: @PaulGroke Yes there is. The function `offsetByCodePoints` (it redirects to `Character.offsetByCodePoints`) is like 50 lines long with loops and stuff, meanwhile `charCount` is just a one liner with a numeric `if`, so I guess there is a lot of performance loss.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I don't understand your comment. Why would outputting XML cause this answer to misbehave?

Comment: @Gili the answer is fine. He was referring to @Jonathan Feinberg's comment in which he advocates for using `charAt()` which is a bad idea

Comment: "If you know you'll be dealing with characters outside the BMP" this is a bad omen.

Comment: Small modification to make it more `continue`-friendly: `final int length = s.length();
for (int codepoint, offset = 0; offset < length; offset += Character.charCount(codepoint)) {
   codepoint = s.codePointAt(offset);
   // do something with the codepoint
}`

Comment: Proposed approach brakes the rule of not changing the value of loop counter from within the body of the loop itself.

Comment: @user07 What rule?

Comment: @JonathanFeinberg I'm referring to SonarQube rule https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1994 labeled as critical. It is raised in the case when counter is incremented in the body of loop method instead of being incremented in a dedicated its increment clause.

Comment: @user07 That's a silly rule of thumb that only makes sense for very basic loops. This is a more complex case which justifies an exception.

Comment: As a supplement, `String rune = new String(new int[]{codepoint}, 0, 1);` can be used to turn a codepoint into a readable single-char UTF-8 string

Answer (score 87):

Java 8 added [`CharSequence#codePoints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) which returns an `IntStream` containing the code points.
You can use the stream directly to iterate over them:

```
string.codePoints().forEach(c -> ...);
```

or with a for loop by collecting the stream into an array:

```
for(int c : string.codePoints().toArray()){
    ...
}
```

These ways are probably more expensive than [Jonathan Feinbergs's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527891/3179759), but they are faster to read/write and the performance difference will usually be insignificant.

Comment: `for (int c : (Iterable<Integer>) () -> string.codePoints().iterator())` also works.

Comment: Slightly shorter version of @saka1029:s code: `for (int c : (Iterable<Integer>) string.codePoints()::iterator) ...`

Answer (score 9):

Thought I'd add a workaround method that works with foreach loops ([ref](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5003547)), plus you can convert it to java 8's new [String#codePoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27798012/32453) method easily when you move to java 8:

You can use it with foreach like this:

```
 for(int codePoint : codePoints(myString)) {
   ....
 }
```

Here's the method:

```
public static Iterable<Integer> codePoints(final String string) {
  return new Iterable<Integer>() {
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
      return new Iterator<Integer>() {
        int nextIndex = 0;
        public boolean hasNext() {
          return nextIndex < string.length();
        }
        public Integer next() {
          int result = string.codePointAt(nextIndex);
          nextIndex += Character.charCount(result);
          return result;
        }
        public void remove() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

Or alternately if you just want to convert a string to an array of int codepoints (if your code could use a codepoint int array more easily) (might use more RAM than the above approach):

```
 public static List<Integer> stringToCodePoints(String in) {
    if( in == null)
      throw new NullPointerException("got null");
    List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final int length = in.length();
    for (int offset = 0; offset < length; ) {
      final int codepoint = in.codePointAt(offset);
      out.add(codepoint);
      offset += Character.charCount(codepoint);
    }
    return out;
  }
```

Thankfully uses "codePointAt" which safely handles the surrogate pair-ness of UTF-16 (java's internal string representation).

Answer (score 6):

Iterating over code points is filed as a feature request at Sun.

See [Bug Report](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-5003547)

There is also an example on how to iterate over String CodePoints there.

Comment: Java 8 now has a codePoints() method built in to String:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints