# How does Java 16 bit chars support Unicode?

Tags: java, unicode

Javas char is 16 bit, yet Unicode have far more characters - how does Java deal with that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java Strings are UTF-16 (big endian), so a Unicode code point can be one or two characters. Under this encoding, Java can represent the code point U+1D50A (*MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL G*) using the chars `0xD835 0xDD0A` (String literal `"\uD835\uDD0A"`). The [Character](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class provides methods for converting to/from code points.

```
// Unicode code point to char array
char[] math_fraktur_cap_g = Character.toChars(0x1D50A);
```

Comment: Why are we not using `int` type `math_fraktur_cap_g` to read surrogate pairs of non-BMP? as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112474/3317808)

Answer (score 13):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

> In computing, UTF-16 (16-bit
>   UCS/Unicode Transformation Format) is
>   a variable-length character encoding
>   for Unicode, capable of encoding the
>   entire Unicode repertoire. The
>   encoding form maps each character to a
>   sequence of 16-bit words. Characters
>   are known as code points and the
>   16-bit words are known as code units.
>   For characters in the Basic
>   Multilingual Plane (BMP) the resulting
>   encoding is a single 16-bit word. For
>   characters in the other planes, the
>   encoding will result in a pair of
>   16-bit words, together called a
>   surrogate pair. All possible code
>   points from U+0000 through U+10FFFF,
>   except for the surrogate code points
>   U+D800–U+DFFF (which are not
>   characters), are uniquely mapped by
>   UTF-16 regardless of the code point's
>   current or future character assignment
>   or use.

Comment: And see my previous answer in SO for how to correctly iterate over all of the characters in a Java String. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527856/how-can-i-iterate-through-the-unicode-codepoints-of-a-java-string/1527891#1527891

Answer (score 3):

Java uses UTF-16 for strings - basically means that characters are variable width. Most of them fit in 16 bits, but those outside Basic Multilingual Pane occupy 32 bits. It's very similar to UTF-8 scheme.