# How java handles characters which don't fit in 2 bytes

Tags: java, character-encoding

We know that java character is 2 byte Unicode character. Assuming you are using UTF-8 character encoding, size of Unicode character can be more than 2 byte depending upon which character you are using.

My question is then how does java handles these types of characters which take more than 2 bytes. Do java allots more than 2 bytes to character in this case or it does some thing else?

Please explain.

Comment: Read the docs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Java store UTF-16 characters in its 16-bit char type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112435/how-does-java-store-utf-16-characters-in-its-16-bit-char-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) uses [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) as an internal encoding. So, characters outside the BMP are stored as two Java `char`, which require 4 bytes of storage. There is an API for [accessing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29) a `String` as a sequence of Unicode code points which handles encoding and decoding these "surrogate pairs" transparently.

Answer (score 2):

The source code for `String` is publicly available. It uses, among other things, the `Character.toSurrogates(int, char[], int)` method which is implemented as such

```
static void toSurrogates(int codePoint, char[] dst, int index) {
    // We write elements "backwards" to guarantee all-or-nothing
    dst[index+1] = lowSurrogate(codePoint);
    dst[index] = highSurrogate(codePoint);
}
```

A `String` has a backing `char[]`. When it needs to store a character that doesn't fit in 2 bytes, it stores it in two chars (4 bytes). Now obviously, this is called appropriately, ie. the `String` method knows which index it's storing the codepoint into and increments it so that the next character is 2 positions away.