# UTF-16 string : how to process over U+10000?

Tags: unicode, utf-16

As we know, UTF-16 is variable-length when there is a character over U+10000.

However, .Net, Java and Windows `WCHAR` UTF-16 string is treated as if they are fixed-length... What happens if I use over U+10000?

And if they process over U+10000, how do they process? For example, in .Net and Java `char` is 16bit. so one `char` cannot process over U+10000..

(.net, java and windows is just example.. I'm talking about how to process over U+10000. But I think I'd rather know how they process over U+10000, for my understanding)

---

thanks to @dystroy, I know how they process. But there is one problem: If string use UTF-16 surrogate, a random access operation, such as `str[3]`, is O(N) algorithm because any character can be 4-byte or 2-byte! How is this problem treated?

Comment: TLDR : some characters simply are spread over more than one Java char...

Comment: @dystroy Um.. Do we have no chance about random access is O(N)? that sounds bad..

Comment: What kind of answer do you really want ? Yes accessing a random code point in a string is costly.

Comment: @dystroy that's an answer which I want, even if I seem not to be satisfied... Anyway, if so, O(N) is required at each string-related operations to support over U+10000? oh;;

Comment: If you have specific question about efficiency of access, you should ask it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered the first part of the question in [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112435/how-does-java-store-utf-16-characters-in-its-16-bit-char-type)  : Basically, some characters simply are spread over more than one Java `char`.

To answer the second part related to random access to unicode points `str[3]`, there are more than one method :

- [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) is careless and only handle chars in a fast and obvious way
- [codePointAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29) returns a 32 bits int (but need a char index)
- `codePointCount` counts code points

And yes, counting the code points **is** costly and basically `O(N)`. Here's how it's done in Java :

```
2665    static int More ...codePointCountImpl(char[] a, int offset, int count) {
2666        int endIndex = offset + count;
2667        int n = 0;
2668        for (int i = offset; i < endIndex; ) {
2669            n++;
2670            if (isHighSurrogate(a[i++])) {
2671                if (i < endIndex && isLowSurrogate(a[i])) {
2672                    i++;
2673                }
2674            }
2675        }
2676        return n;
2677    }
```

UTF-16 is a bad format to deal with code points, especially if you leave the BMP. Most programs simply don't handle code points, which is the reason this format is usable. Most String operations are fast because they **don't deal** with code points : all standard API take `char` indexes as arguments, not worrying about what kind of rune points they do have behind.

Comment: Thank you! so, Is ignoring over U+10000 not bad choice? I guess I should consider UTF-32 if I work with over U+10000..

Comment: I don't understand your need. What do you do with your code points ?

Comment: Well, I'm writing a string library and I think I should know this problem perfectly..

Comment: Not knowing your problem, you probably shouldn't use UTF-32. UTF-8 is most often the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this problem is not treated at all. Many languages and libraries that use UTF-8 or UTF-16 do substrings or indexes by accessing *code units*, not *code points*. That is `str[3]` will just return the surrogate character in that case. Of course access is constant-time in that case, but for anything outside the BMP (or ASCII) you have to be careful what you do.

If you're lucky there are methods to access code points, e.g. in Java `String.codePointAt`. And in this case you have to scan the string from the start and determine code point boundaries.

Generally, even accessing code points doesn't gain you very much, though, only at library level. Strings often are used eventually to interact with the user and in that case graphemes or visual string length become more important than code points. And you have even more processing to do in that case.

Comment: Oh, in my question, `str[3]` means the third character.. and java is just example. I'm talking about HOW to process, not what java method processes.

Comment: ASCII ? Hopefully we have more than ASCII in 32 bits. Maybe this part of your answer isn't clear.

Comment: @dystroy: UTF-8 and UTF-16 are variable-length. One makes access to ASCII characters straightforward, the other makes access to BMP characters straightforward. For everything else you'll have to handle the variable-length issue. That's what was meant there. That being said, unless you process strings by the tens or hundreds of gibibytes you're unlikely to really notice the difference in naïve indexing or actually finding code points.

Comment: Oh, you were talking of UTF-8. OK. I think this makes the answer more complex though.

Comment: @ikh: It makes little difference. Java is just an example in my answer too. If you want to, I can add C# or Qt to that as well, but *it doesn't matter*. Most things that gained unicode support early and thus are stuck with UTF-16 go the easy route and ignore the code point route (unless they're specifically built for text processing, but then they're probably using UTF-32 internally anyway) and just give you code points. Python is a nice exception to that rule by even completely hiding the underlying byte representation of Unicode strings.

Comment: @Joey Um.. so I don't have to think about this problem, and just do as if UTF-16 is fixed-length, right?

Comment: @ikh, none of us knows what you're up to. If in doubt, just use a decent framework or library that supports Unicode and ignore anything that isn't a problem yet.

Comment: @Joey In fact, I'm writing "string library"...