# utf char in Java

Tags: java, utf

im trying to store a utf char as following:

```
char utfChr1 = '\u1F6BF';
```

wich give me an **invalid character constant** error.

```
char utfChr2 = '\uE517';
```

works fine. I can set the char to FFFF and it works without compiler error. But anything over 65535 (10000) gives me that error. What can I do?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112435/how-does-java-store-utf-16-characters-in-its-16-bit-char-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `char` is 16-bits in Java. Therefore there is only support for UTF-16.

I would say "don't try to use that as a constant", but I'm not sure what you intend to do with it. You could always read the value from an external source, in an encoding that supports the character you're looking for.

Edit:
I see that you wish to use the character [SHOWER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6bf/index.htm) :)

As you can see from the link, it's encoded as 2 chars in UTF-16: `\uD83D\uDEBF`