# Why cannot use special character(over 10000 unicode ) file name in SD card?

Tags: android, unicode, utf-8, filesystems, android-sdcard

Recently I got a trouble to copy a file to removable SD card from internal SD card in Android.

This file has a special character "snake"(http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f40d/index.htm).

It can save to internal SD card.
But it cannot copy to removable SD card.
I tried to copy to removable SD card from my PC. 
But it was failed, too.

So that I have created a code to change special character to something.

```
for(int i =0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if(input.codePointAt(i) > 0xFFFF) { //check is it special character?
            //change string!!!!! 
            i ++;
        } else {
            builder.append(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }
```

It worked so that i could resolve my problem. 
But I want to know the reason of

**why I cannot copy to removable SD card which has a special character(unicode 10000 over like U+1f40d).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Latest (and possibly final) Answer :**

Recently I formatted a SD Card through an android phone (Jellybean) just to check the newly formatted file system. It turned out to be `FAT` system.

`FAT` systems *(any version)* do not support `UTF-16` Long Filenames. It only supports `UCS-2` Long Filenames. (The former supports Surrogate pairs while the latter doesn't)

From the second link:

> ...whereas **UCS-2** is **limited to BMP characters**. These encodings are practical because the length in units is the number of characters.

This could explain the 'Snake' character issue with your device. Can you confirm the filesystem for us?

Your Internal Filesystem, on the other hand, would depend on the manufacturer.
Check the 4th link which confirms this.

1. [UTF-16 vs UCS-2](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-ucs-2-and-utf-16/)
2. [Unicode Encoding](http://unicodebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/unicode_encodings.html#ucs-2-ucs-4-utf-16-and-utf-32)
3. [Wikipedia Link to FAT filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table)
4. [Android Internal FS](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95678/which-filesystem-do-android-use)

**Previous Answer(2):**

I tried to replicate the scenario in my PC with 'Snake' Unicode in the source file name and copying using `Files` class and well it copied successfully.

Code used:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class abc {
    /**
     * @param arg
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {      
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.appendCodePoint(128013);     
        File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("testFile" + sb.toString(), ".txt");
        File dirTrgt = new File("C:\\"+tmpFile.getName());
        Files.copy(tmpFile.toPath(), dirTrgt.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        tmpFile.deleteOnExit();
    }
}
```

**Previous Answer (1):**

> The range of valid code points is U+0000 to U+10FFFF.

In Java, `char` has a strict length of 2 bytes --> 16 bits --> 0xFFFF (max value)

The value (`int` value that you get from `#getCodePointAt(int)`) supports all the code-points. (Unicode characters are called code-points)

<s>So, when you encounter a character `> 0xFFFF` your `input.charAt(i)` (most likely) returns an overflowed `char` which is `!= input.getCodePointAt(i)`</s>

Little about UTF-16:

- BMP - Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) is the code point range U+0000
  to U+FFFF.
- Any characters above the range are termed as Supplementary Characters. Such characters are represented using **pair** of `char` values.
- Supplementary character are made up of a **high surrogate** -- value range of 0xD800 to 0xDBFF -- and a **low surrogate** -- value range of 0xDC00 to 0xDFFF--

From the link which you have given in the Question we can see this. Value for Snake for UTF-16:

> UTF-16 (hex) --   0xD83D 0xDC0D (d83ddc0d)

For more info refer below links:

[Android Doc for Character Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html)

[how-does-java-store-utf-16-characters-in-its-16-bit-char-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112435/how-does-java-store-utf-16-characters-in-its-16-bit-char-type)

Comment: JAVA uses UTF-16, so those high code points are encoded as a surrogate pair. So the string `""` (the snake) is encoded as 2 chars: `0xd83d` and `0xdc0d`. As pointed out in the doc you linked, those code points are handled by **static int toCodePoint(char high, char low)** and **static int toChars(int codePoint, char[] dst, int dstIndex)**.

Comment: Hmm that being said, I just tried creating a file like that using the file manager on the SD card on an Android phone and failed. It's possible that Android, or the file system on that card, doesn't allow characters above U+FFFF. I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: Hi @boxed__l. 
In Java, that snake encoded 2character pair. And your answer is very helpful to me to understand about Java UTF.
Yes, it saves to android main drive successfully. But, 
did you try to save to "removable SD card"? 
In "Removable SD card", that snake file name cant be saved.
Do you know why it cannot be saved?

Comment: I accept your answer. And please let us know if you know about my above question.

Comment: SD Card it use FAT! totally matched!  Thank you so much! I respect you!