# Why can’t StringUtils.join accept a StringCharacterIterator?

Tags: java, iterator, apache-commons, apache-stringutils

The following code should work, since `join` accepts an iterator as argument:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join;
import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;

…

join(new StringCharacterIterator("A String"), " ");
```

Alas, it doesn’t. Can somebody explain to me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `StringCharacterIterator` inherits from and only from  `CharacterIterator`. A `CharacterIterator` does not inherit from a generic `Iterator`, which is what `join` wants.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/CharacterIterator.html

Comment: so the answer is that the Java standard library is a mess. So i need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925130/java-how-to-get-iteratorcharacter-from-string)

Comment: @flying sheep: Partly, yes. When you deal with cross-libraries, like Oracle/Java with Apache, it gets even messier.

Comment: No. The fact that it ends with Iterator doesn't mean it must have the same interface. A HashTable doesn't have much in common with a WoodenTable.

Comment: I don’t want to argue about this. “`Iterator`” is an unambiguous term in most programming languages (one of which being Java). You just don’t call something an iterator if it doesn’t implement the builtin interface of the same name.

Comment: @flying sheep Actually if you look at the javadoc for the Iterator class it talks explicitly about a collection (which an array is not, or there wouldn't be the utility method to convert it to a collection).  Also a String is a character array, which as is shown is not a collection in Oracle land.  My guess is it is called `StringCharacterIterator` because `CharacterArrayTraversalAgent` didn't sound as nice.

Comment: when did java ever care about niceness? it is an inconsitent grown-into-a-thicket kind of language and library. and there are much worse names in there than `CharacterArrayTraversalAgent`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the join method takes two arguments : an iterator and a separator string or char.

And if you look at the [javadoc of StringCharacterIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/StringCharacterIterator.html), you'll see that this class does not implement `java.util.Iterator`.

Comment: Ah, of course, i forgot to type the second argument. It is in my code, however.