# Explain how this lambda can be assigned to an Iterable

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I came across some clever code to convert an Iterator to a Stream from Karol on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439780/how-to-create-a-java-8-stream-from-an-iterator/23442909#23442909). I have to admit that I don't completely understand how the lambda is allowed to be assigned to the `Iterable` type in the following code...

```
static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToFiniteStream(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
    final Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator;
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}
```

I decided to write my own small test to ensure that it compiles and executes, and it does.

```
public void printsStream_givenIterator()
{
    Iterator<String> iterator = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").iterator();
    final Iterable<String> iterable = () -> iterator;
    StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}

// prints: abc
```

My understanding is that the lambda `() -> iterator` is acting as a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) function.

[Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) isn't a [FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) so how can it be assigned this lambda?

Comment: Its the same as: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html#section2 which assigns a lambda to runnable. It is explained here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html#section1

Comment: the annotation is not required, on the last link you have provided: "However, the compiler will treat any interface meeting the definition of a functional interface as a functional interface **regardless of whether or not a FunctionalInterface annotation is present** on the interface declaration."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`() -> iterator` is *not* “acting as a `Supplier` function”. Lambda expressions can be assigned to any congruent functional interface type. And there is no requirement for a functional interface to be annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`. You can create an `Iterable` with a lambda expression, which will implement the `Iterable.iterator()` method, which is the only `abstract` method of that interface. However, implementing it by returning the same `Iterator` instance each time may violate the expectation of being able to iterate this object multiple times (which is the reason [why `Stream` doesn’t implement `Iterable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130131/2711488) despite having an `iterator()` method).

This solution will work in this narrow context, but isn’t clever.

The sequence

```
final Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator; … iterable.spliterator()
```

just introduces an additional step before `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0)`, which is how the `default` method of `Iterable.spliterator()` is implemented.

So

```
static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToFiniteStream(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
    final Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator;
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}
```

is just a less efficient variant of

```
static <T> Stream<T> iteratorToFiniteStream(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
}
```

If you compare this to the accepted answer of the Q&A you’ve linked, you’ll see that it is exactly that, but that answer takes the opportunity of passing specific `characteristics` instead of `0`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give me a thoughtful and detailed answer

Answer (score 8):

As you've pointed out, assignment from a lambda expression is only valid if the target is a functional interface.  This is described in [section 15.27.3 of the JLS: Type of a Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3).

> A lambda expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

Jumping to [section 9.8: Functional Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8), we can see the definition of a functional interface.

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract method (aside from the methods of Object), and thus represents a single function contract.

[`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) does satisfy the criteria for a functional interface, because it has only one abstract method: `iterator()`.  (The 2 additional `default` methods do not violate the criteria, because they are not abstract.)  Therefore, the assignment is valid.