# Convert XSLT function (string-to-codepoints) to Java

Tags: java, xslt

How can I "translate" this XSLT code to Java ?

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(string-to-codepoints(upper-case($char)) - string-to-codepoints('A'))+10"/>
```

I only know that: "The **fn:string-to-codepoints** function returns a sequence of **xs:integer** values representing the Unicode code points."

From the example that is given in (http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_string-to-codepoints.html) :

string-to-codepoints('a') = 97

I found this:

```
char ch = 'a';
System.out.println(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) ch));
```

But I get : **\u0061**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single `char` you can just cast it to `int` to get the decimal value:

```
System.out.println((int)ch);
```

For a `String` there's `.toCharArray()` to convert it to a `char[]` but that isn't quite the same as a "sequence of codepoints" if the String involves Unicode characters outside the BMP (i.e. above U+FFFF), which are represented in Java as a surrogate pair of two `char` values.  To handle surrogates properly you would need to use a technique like [the one described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527891/592139).

To answer the specific question you ask, you can do

```
number(string-to-codepoints(upper-case($char)) - string-to-codepoints('A'))+10
```

in Java as

```
char ch = // wherever you get $char from
int num = Character.toUpperCase(ch) - 'A' + 10;
```

since `char` is an integer type in Java and you can add or subtract char values like any other number.

But this will probably only give you a sensible answer when the initial `ch` is an ASCII letter.

Answer (score 1):

You print the value as unicode escape sequence; XSLT prints a decimal value.

This should work much better:

```
System.out.println("a".codePointAt(0));
```