# Emojicons Send face icons not work, send number icons work

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, xmpp, emoji

When I send emojis nums icons, 1,2,3,4,5.... send correctly, But when I try send emojis icons how smile or others ... not send nothing ...

My debug show a face smile, but not send. why ?
then seems to not clean the buffer, and when you rewrite, the activity is closed, but not when using numbers icons emojis.

The listener not called, when I use icons fases, but yes when I use icons numbers.

[image]

```
public void sendMessageServer()throws XMPPException{
        Message msg= new Message();
        String tim =  "            "+time;
        Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(CurrentUsernameClick+"@delive", messageListener);
        if(message_list.getText().toString()!=null && message_list.length()>0){
            String text = message_list.getText().toString();
            msg.setBody(message_list.getText().toString() +tim);
            chat.sendMessage(message_list.getText().toString() + tim);
            addNewMessage(new Messages(msg.getBody(), true));
            UserDataAccesObject.createMessage(id, id, msg.getBody(), usernameSession, CurrentUsernameClick, time);
            message_list.setText("");
        }
    }
```

DEBUG SHOW :

[image]
[image] I send correctly numbers, but smiles face not.

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

I have 2 ideas : 1 (orc) 2 (ASCII)

1 -

> I think that I need recognize characters not? with library OCR not ?

in my debugger, show [?] with icons, I think that is because not recognize character correctly, or am I wrong?

2 -

> Or can be ASCII ?

Answer (score 2):

Try showing the hex values of the characters in your strings.  You may find that the first one shows 0x0031 (DIGIT ONE) and 0x20DE (COMBINING ENCLOSING SQUARE), which are two Unicode code points that combine together to make "1⃞".  The second one may show 0xD83D 0xDE03, which is UTF-16 for a single Unicode character "" (U+1F603 SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH).  Next look at what actually gets written on the wire.  In hex, the first one should be: 31E2839E and the second should be F09F9883, both of which are the UTF-8 encodings for their respective Unicode code points.

Several libraries have bugs dealing with characters higher than U+FFFF.  It may be that you have run into one of these.  If that is the case, you might see something like EDA0BDEDB883 (hex) for the smilie's output.  This is *invalid* UTF-8, and should be rejected by a server compliant with [RFC 6120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120).

Comment: Not directly, not send nothing.
I think that is method to send wrong(algoritmic), because my listview/edittext/sqlite/adapter/Toast  recognize the icons (as I showed above), but not chat.sendMessage, not recognize icons, https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/52552?tstart=0 , How I can do, to recognize icons of characters special, to send?

Comment: I tried : name = new String(message_list.getText().toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1"); and I get : smile : "??", word = "word" , icon number 1 = "1?"

Comment: I'm going crazy trying encodings: name = new String; (message_list.getText () toString () getBytes ("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-16"..) , Returns chinese characters, I do not know the Chinese language.

Comment: Any idea ? is very important for me

Comment: No amount of ISO-8859-1 is going to help.  UTF-16 is not going to help.  You likely need to file a bug with your XMPP library project (ASmack?), asking them to test with Unicode codepoints higher than U+FFFF.

Comment: Then I do? 
I can not do anything about the problem? send ascii and detect the listener? I can do anything? I can not waste hours and hours of work.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 only encodes characters less than U+FFFF.  You are trying to encode U+1F603, which is higher than U+FFFF.  You have that character in a Java string.  Java strings are UTF-16 inherently, which is why it looks like you have two characters.  That one codepoint, U+1F603, is in your Java string as two halves, known as a "surrogate pair" (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 for more info).  Your XMPP library is responsible for turning UTF-16 strings into UTF-8 in order to produce valid XMPP.  If it's not, you either have to fix the library or get someone else to fix it.

Comment: Alternately, just send the string ":)" and let the other side turn it into an emoticon, which is what most XMPP clients do.

Comment: not is easy ":)", my icons are set by emojicon, or how I can do ?

Comment: You could write a regular expression, but then you'd just have questions about Unicode regular expressions. Seriously, just ask your library provider for help.

Comment: I remember when I was encryptación long time ago when i was learning java.
I remember one day Told Me: Everything you send "encode" and the listener hears, "ALWAYS" you can get the actual data.

Comment: Now I can send utf-16 with this word: "jaja" = "<?><?>jaja" is a avanze, now I have to decode utf-16 Correctly, see this example http://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Send smile using htmlescape using apache common util lib it works for me

Comment: Where I can find library of htmlescape for android ?

Comment: Works, (api 16 = @SuppressLint), but now return characters unknown for me "&#12851"(smile) how I can covert this number in  ?

Comment: send this character in the message and while receiving it use use StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml();

Comment: 1 up please, if you like the answer

Comment: Yeah, this will work.  If you don't want to take a dependency, you can run through each codepoint in the string using this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1527891/8388), replacing each codepoint higher than U+FFFF with an XML escape sequence.