# How do I compare each character of a String while accounting for characters with length > 1?

Tags: java, string, unicode, character-encoding, utf-16

I have a variable string that might contain any unicode character. One of these unicode characters is the han .

The thing is that this "han" character has `"".length() == 2` but is written in the string as a single character.

Considering the code below, how would I iterate over all characters and compare each one while considering the fact it might contain one character with length greater than 1?

```
for ( int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++ ) {
    char character = string.charAt( i );
    if ( character == '' ) {
        // Fail, it interprets as 2 chars =/
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
This question is not a duplicate. This asks how to iterate for each character of a String while considering characters that contains `.length() > 1` (character not as a `char` type but as the representation of a written symbol). This question does not require previous knowledge of how to iterate over unicode code points of a Java String, although an answer mentioning that may also be correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527856/how-can-i-iterate-through-the-unicode-codepoints-of-a-java-string

Comment: Should I use "symbol" instead of "character" in this question to make it clear?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int hanCodePoint = "".codePointAt(0);
for (int i = 0; i < string.length();) {
    int currentCodePoint = string.codePointAt(i);
    if (currentCodePoint == hanCodePoint) {
        // do something here.
    }
    i += Character.charCount(currentCodePoint);
}
```

Comment: No way to compare with single quotes `''`?

Comment: unfortunately, no.  `` is a valid Unicode character, but is not expressible as a single Java `char`, which is what you would need to be able to put it in single quotes.  If you try, you will notice that you won't even be able to compile that. A java `char` can only represent Unicode characters up to code point 65,535.  Past that, you need 2 surrogate `char`s to represent the character, or simply use a `String`.  Very annoying, I agree.

Answer (score 9):

The `String.charAt` and `String.length` methods treat a String as a sequence of UTF-16 code units.  You want to treat the string as Unicode code-points.

Look at the "code point" methods in the String API:

- `codePointAt(int index)` returns the (32 bit) code point at a given code-unit index
- `offsetByCodePoints(int index, int codePointOffset)` returns the code-unit index corresponding to `codePointOffset` code-points from the code-unit at `index`.
- `codePointCount(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` counts the code-points between two code-unit indexes.

Indexing the string by code point index is a bit tricky, especially if the string is long and you want to do it efficiently.  However, it is a do-able, albeit that the code is rather cumbersome.

@sstan's answer is one solution.

Answer (score 3):

This will be simpler if you treat both the string and the data you're searching for as `String`s. If you just need to test for the presence of that character:

```
if (string.contains("") {
    // do something here.
}
```

If you specifically need the index where that character appears:

```
int i = string.indexOf("");
if (i >= 0) {
    // do something with i here.
}
```

And if you really need to iterate through every code point, see [How can I iterate through the unicode codepoints of a Java String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527856/how-can-i-iterate-through-the-unicode-codepoints-of-a-java-string) .

Comment: What is the cost of time by using `.contains` or `.indexOf` for all characters I am testing? I am looking for a more generic approach instead of using `.contains` or `.indexOf` only for characters with `length > 1`.

Comment: This answer seems to be more closer to the question than iterating over unicode code points, although sacrificing some performance.

Answer (score -4):

An ASCII character takes half the amount a Unicode char does, so it's logical that the han character is of length 2. It not an ASCII char, nor a Unicode letter. If it were the second case, the letter would be displayed correctly.

Comment: An ASCII character in Unicode is the same size as it is in ASCII.  What you're more referring to are multi-byte Unicode characters.