# Character length is 1 in Python, but 2 in Kotlin

Tags: python, android, kotlin

I'm iterating over a String in Kotlin and noticed that Kotlin views a certain Chinese character as having length 2. The same character has length 1 in Python 3.8.

Kotlin:

```
>>> "".length
2
```

Python:

```
>>> len("")
1
```

Why is that the case and how can I iterate over the string in Kotlin character by character?

Comment: The "why" sounds like its because its a double-byte character. I've never used kotlin though

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527856/how-can-i-iterate-through-the-unicode-codepoints-of-a-java-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with a surrogate pair. Surrogate pairs are UTF's way of encoding certain characters.

That  cannot be represented as one `Char`. You can check that by attempting to define it as a char literal.

```
val someChar = '' // Error: Too many character in character literal ""
```

So how to count those properly? Kotlin's standard library has a function for that ([`hasSurrogatePairAt`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/has-surrogate-pair-at.html)) which you could put in an extension function like that:

```
fun String.countSurrogatePairs() = withIndex().count {
    hasSurrogatePairAt(it.index)
}
```

Usage:

```
println("".countSurrogatePairs()) // 1
println("".countSurrogatePairs()) // 2
```

So, Python seems to already handle that.