# How to escape the < and ≤ symbols in xml?

Tags: xml, escaping

I want to create a string `<res>` in android as below:

```
<string name="bmi0">0: BMI≤18.5</string>
<string name="bmi1">1: 18.5<BMI≤24</string>
<string name="bmi2">2: 24<BMI≤27</string>
```

But i shown the error of "Tag start is not closed".

I tried to put a `\` symbol in front, but it doesn't work, it has shown the same error.

```
<string name="bmi0">0: BMI\≤18.5</string>
<string name="bmi1">1: 18.5<BMI\≤24</string>
<string name="bmi2">2: 24<BMI\≤27</string>
```

How to escape the special XML symbols ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will have to escape those symbols as following:

- `<` will be `&lt;`
- `>` will be `&gt;`

The `≤` character doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Doesn't this entierly miss the point of the "less than or equal" sign being used, ≤ ?

Comment: @peter.petrov Ah, I guess the OP's errors are only from the use of regular <.

Comment: I think I answered first on this question btw :) @kocko Isn't this &le; actually &lt; ?!

Comment: it shown "unescaped & or nonterminated character/entity reference" error. when i use "&lt"

Comment: you will have to add a colon ( `;` ) after it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape those symbols for XML.

[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Answer (score 3):

As said, for the `<` and `>`, you can use this:

```
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
```

You need to do this because the `<` and `>` aren't allowed in XML, so you need to `escape` them. You do that by typing: `&` + `specific code for your character` + `;`, when you show this string, this will be recognized as being the special character (`<` or `>`).

You also wanted the `smaller or equal` sign (≤), which is afaik allowed in XML, so just use `≤`.

These are the characters you have to escape:

```
"   =   &quot;
'   =   &apos;
<   =   &lt;
>   =   &gt;
&   =   &amp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents: guava 15 introduced Escapers, especially for this situations:

```
 Escaper escaper = XmlEscapers.xmlAttributeEscaper();
 String result = escaper.escape("<>");
 System.out.println(result); // &lt;&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Unicode sequences for special characters.

You can find some of them here: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2200-22FF

Use it like this:

```
\u2264
```

will be converted to `≤`

Comment: why it has +1? \uxxxx is not for xml

Answer (score 1):

use

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4301267/2740014

to escape the strings and then put them into your xml.

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(stringHere);
```

Is the needed thing i think.

Answer (score 1):

Use Unicode

For    `<`  use  `\u003c`
For    `>` `\u003e` and 
For    `≤` `\u2264`

For getting unicode of any String use the following method

```
public static String getUnicode(String input){
    String output = "";
    for(char c:input.toCharArray()){
        output +="\\u" + Integer.toHexString(c|0x10000).substring(1) ;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: why it has +1? \uxxxx is not for xml

Comment: @Selvin this is tagged android, and in strings.xml it 100% works PLUS its the only way to do it with some special chars, like "non breaking-hyphen" \uXXXX is even SUGGESTED BY LINT (e.g if you type "...")

Comment: sure the only way .... `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root><test name="&#8209;"/></root>` xml notation is &#XXXX; or &#xHHHH;

Comment: @selvin yes you're right (plus I just saw, that lint is not suggesting it anymore) BUT still, why is it thing working, if its not for xml?

Comment: from The Source http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-charref ... there is no single word about \u notation

Comment: I still don't see why it's _wrong_. It answers the question and works in android. (why? Probably because the string is first parsed and _then_ translated)