# How to add apache commons collections in Android Studio (Gradle)

Tags: android, gradle

Im trying to use ListUtils
but when I ran the app I got this error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.meridianaspect.wiw-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

So I guess I have to import that library via gradle somehow, but I dont know how to do that?

Comment: HttpClient was already part of Android but obsolete from API 23+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32157466/1085264

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place the jar file in the libs folder in the root of your module. Then File -> Project Settings. In the left side choose the module where you want to add this lib, in the right side choose tab Dependencies. In the bottom press Plus sign and click File dependency. Then choose your jar and sync project

Comment: Is there a way to do this just by placing some text in Gradle and having to deal with jar files and modules?

Comment: @J.K. you mean simply drop jars and not specifying each jar?

Comment: No, I mean not dropping any jars, just telling gradle what repo to get them from

Comment: like this, for example:     compile 'com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader:library:1.2.0'

Comment: Try 'compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'

Comment: on pressing plus sign another option is Library dependency and there is search - type the name and search for the library you interested in

Comment: gradle based projects should not be adding dependencies by editing the Project Settings, they should be adding them as dependencies in the build.gradle

Comment: @Novaterata any source for such declaration?

Comment: In the first place, It's apache commons, they should be using a maven dependency, not the jar file. Here is how to do it with the GUI, but it's easy enough to just add it to your build.gradle https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-dependency-diagram.html#gradle_generate

Comment: @Novaterata even in case of adding not jar, but maven dependency, what's the problem of using UI?
It ends up in the same `build.gradle` file
And I haven't heard, that using UI is deprecated, please send me the link for that announcement

Comment: @OlegOsipenko I must be misunderstanding, whenever I had done something like this in the past it did not update the build.gradle, but just the IntelliJ project file. Apologies if that's no longer the case.

Comment: @Novaterata not sure about IntelliJ. But in the question it was said about Android Studio. Although it's built on top of IntelliJ Idea, it still differs. Maybe that is one of differences. But not sure. In AS it's definitely doesn't matter how you do it, via UI or by hand

Answer (score 492):

Pick the ones you need and add them to `build.gradle`'s dependencies block:

I recommend checking the link to make sure you are getting the latest version. Feel free to suggest edits.

**collections**: [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4)

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
```

**lang**: [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3)

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
```

**compress**: [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress)

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.19'
```

**net**: [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net)

```
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
```

**io**: [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io)

```
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
```

**exec** [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-exec)

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-exec:1.3'
```

**codec** [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec)

```
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.13'
```

**http** [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient)

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.10'
```

**validator** [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator)

```
implementation 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6'
```

**math** [(link)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3)

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
```

---

See all of the [Apache libraries here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons)

Comment: and for lang, `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4`. source: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4

Comment: and for net, compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'

Comment: @Chad Could you please tell in which dependency, `FilenameUtils` is?

Comment: @Iqbal it's in IO: `compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'`

Comment: How come collections doesn't have CircularFifoBuffer ? I can't find it. Same goes to BufferUtils

Comment: Do you why there are bunch of strange `commons-codec` on search.maven.org? @ChadBingham

Comment: And `commons-vfs` and `commons-logging` its possible to add

Comment: Don't use this lib. By using this lib, While uploading apk to Google play store, It will show 0 supported devices. Instead use compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'. it works.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking in the Maven Repository for commons-math instead of commons-math3 and wondering why the available versions were all so old.

Comment: Type `implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:+'` and AS would provide a warning to automatically replace the `+` with the known latest version.