# Apache Commons in Android Studio Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apache-commons

Following this answer, I tried adding Apache Commons Collections to my Gradle file:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31496709/10039165

However, when I sync Gradle, I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':App@prodDebug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1.

What is the correct way of adding Apache Commons to Gradle?

Comment: Which gradle version? Have you tried to disable firewall/antivirus? If so, could you add your gradle file?

Comment: @Bedla Version 3.1.3, not able to disable firewall/antivirus (at work).