# Jaxb parsing for < character in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have an XML file as shown below:

```
<headerRule name='modifyCType'
            headerName='Content-Type'
            action='manipulate'
            matchValue='($checkPT18.$chkPT18)&!$checkAnnexb.$chkAnnexb)'
            newValue='<'
            methods='INVITE'>
</headerRule>
```

While unmarshalling using JAXB, it says invalid character `&` on `matchValue='($checkPT18.$chkPT18)&!$checkAnnexb.$chkAnnexb)'` which I replaced with `&amp` and it is working now i.e. `matchValue='($checkPT18.$chkPT18)&amp;!$checkAnnexb.$chkAnnexb)'`.

However, there is another invalid character `<` on `newValue='<'` when I replace it with `&lt` it works fine however it replaces all '<' character with `&lt` including `&ltheaderRule` as shown below:

```
&lt;headerRule name='modifyCType'
            headerName='Content-Type'
            action='manipulate'
            matchValue='($checkPT18.$chkPT18)&amp;!$checkAnnexb.$chkAnnexb)'
            newValue='&lt;'
            methods='INVITE'>
&lt;/headerRule>
```

which I do not want. I want:

```
<headerRule name='modifyCType'
            headerName='Content-Type'
            action='manipulate'
            matchValue='($checkPT18.$chkPT18)&amp;!$checkAnnexb.$chkAnnexb)'
            newValue='&lt;'
            methods='INVITE'>
</headerRule>
```

How to replace < with &lt only for attribute value i.e. newValue using jaxb parsing?

Comment: `newValue='&lt;'` should work.

Comment: @StephenC it works, however, it replaces all < including <headerRule tag like &lt;headerRule, which i don't want

Comment: How can we solve it using jaxb, during parsing

Comment: Your question is really confusing.  Please update the example to reflect your actual problem.  (You have diagnosed and fixed the problems with the `<` and `&` characters by using character references.  So show us the *fixed* XML and get rid of the irrelevant stuff about how you fixed that.)

Comment: @StephenC I have updated question, hope it helps you now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping special character when generating an XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301236/escaping-special-character-when-generating-an-xml-in-java)