# How to escape XML tags?

Tags: java, xml, escaping

There is plenty of utils that can escape values for HTML/XML formats. I was using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml` but it converts also unicode characters `(äöü)` -> `(&#228;&#246;&#252;)`.

What I need is to escape just some XML specific tags such as <, >. (I manually create XML, not with JAXB, please don't ask why).

Answer (score 1):

You can write method to specifically escape certain xml chars like this:

```
public String escapeXml(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;").replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll("\"", "&quot;").replaceAll("'", "&apos;");
}
```

courtesy - [StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml is converting utf8 characters which it should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984875/stringescapeutils-escapexml-is-converting-utf8-characters-which-it-should-not)

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Is it wrong? (geniunely wondering because I'm doing it a similar way and I don't see what the problem with this code is)

Comment: @rococo it's not downvoted lol, it has single upvote and no downvotes

Answer (score 0):

What is your StringEscapeUtil version? 
Because the doc is :

> Note that Unicode characters greater than 0x7f are as of 3.0, no longer escaped.

See : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml-java.lang.String-

So you just may need to update to the latest version (current is 3.6)

You can use this too : 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#ESCAPE_XML10
From `apache.commons.text` instead of `apache.commons.lang3`

Answer (score 0):

Xml values are escaped as mentioned earlier,StringEscapeUtils.

It is best to **use standard/proper names** and not to escape tag name. 
As last resort escape prior to generating the xml and unescape the value when it is parsed.

#### Escape chosen set of WhiteSpace chars

```
private static final String ESC_START = "__x";
private static final String ESC_END = "_";

private final Set<Integer> toEscape = Stream.of((int)' ', 0xA, 0xD, 0xA0,
        0x2002, 0x2003, 0x2004, 0x2005, 0x2006, 0x2007, 0x2008, 0x2009, 0x200A,
        0x205F, 0x3000).collect(Collectors.toSet());

private String escapeName(String name){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<name.length();i++){
        char c = name.charAt(i);
        if (toEscape.contains((int) c)){
            sb.append(ESC_START);
            sb.append(Integer.toString((int) c));
            sb.append(ESC_END);
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ESC_START+"([0-9]+)"+ESC_END);
private String unescapeName(String name){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i=0;
    Matcher found = pattern.matcher(name);
    while(found.find(i)){
        sb.append(name.substring(i,found.start()));
        sb.append((char)(Integer.parseInt(found.group(1))));
        i = found.end();
    }
    sb.append(name.substring(i,name.length()));

    return sb.toString();
}
```