# StringEscapeUtils displays Japanese in unicode

Tags: java, apache, stringescapeutils

I'm trying to escape japanese xml to display as normal japanese string and not unicode xml. I can't use `apache.commons.lang3` and only `apache.commons.lang` is preferred. If you have any other suggestions not in this library feel free to share. Thanks in advance!

`final String xmlToEscape = "言語が良くない";`
`final String escapedXml = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(xmlToEscape);`

Prints:

> &#35328 ;&#35486 ;&#12364 ;&#33391 ;&#12367 ;&#12394 ;&#12356 ;

Should print:

> 言語が良くない

Comment: This might be helpful, [check out this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984875/stringescapeutils-escapexml-is-converting-utf8-characters-which-it-should-not)

Answer (score 0):

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()` in `apache.commons.lang` [always escapes non-ASCII characters](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/LANG_2_6/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang/Entities.java#L864).

If you don't want to escape Japanese characters, you have to pass only the ASCII characters in the string to `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()` like this:

```java
package org.example;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // You will get "&#35328;&#35486;&#12364;&#33391;&#12367;&#12394;&#12356; &lt;ABC&gt;"
        System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("言語が良くない <ABC>"));
        // You will get "言語が良くない &lt;ABC&gt;"
        System.out.println(escapeXml("言語が良くない <ABC>"));
    }

    public static String escapeXml(String str) {
        return Arrays.stream(str.split("")).map(s -> escapeCharacter(s)).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append).toString();
    }

    public static String escapeCharacter(String str) {
        if (str.matches("\\p{ASCII}")) {
            return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(str);
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```