# StringEscapeUtils for character escape

Tags: java

where can i find this class `StringEscapeUtils`  that can automatically escape the characters instead of manualy doing... on my search i found the util called `StringEscapeUtils` but i could not find in my project or i try to download from net but could not find too... is there a way i can make that automated something like this:

```
String testStr = "< > \" &"; 
System.out.println("Escaped : " + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(testStr));
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439298

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to download the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) library and include it in your project as a referenced library.

Comment: but what exactly i need to download, i am new to java

Comment: Download the Commons Lang 3.1 library binary file [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi).

Comment: The StringEscapeUtils class from commons-lang is deprecated as of 3.6. Use StringEscapeUtils class from commons-text.

Answer (score 1):

org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils is a part of the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) package.

Comment: but what exactly i need to download, i am new to java

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi - I recommend the most recent version (zip file)

You'll need a jar file from the distribution. Add it to the project's classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for: org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

See:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: but what exactly i need to download, i am new to java

Comment: "I'm 12, what is this?"