# Exception while replacing backslashes to slashes

Tags: java, jsp, str-replace

in my application I need to prepare a path for XML file inside JSP page. I'm doing someting like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"  prefix="x" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<c:set var="abs_path" value='<%= getServletContext().getRealPath("").replace(" ", "%20").replace("\\", "/") %>' />
```

But there is a problem, I get the followind exception:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

```
An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /users.jsp
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
3: <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
4: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"  prefix="x" %>
5: <!DOCTYPE html>
6: <c:set var="abs_path" value='<%= getServletContext().getRealPath("").replace(" ", "%20").replace("\\", "/") %>' />
```

Apparently it's about this part: `.replace("\\", "/")`
When I delete it, I don't get this exception.

What's that about? I will be very grateful for any clue.

EDIT:

I use this variable in the following way:

```
                <c:import url="file:/${abs_path}/MyProject/xml/users.xml" var="inputDoc" charEncoding="UTF-8" />

                <c:import url="xsl/users_list.xsl"
                        var="stylesheet" charEncoding="UTF-8" />

                <x:transform 
                     xml  = "${inputDoc}"
                     xslt = "${stylesheet}">
                </x:transform>
```

Comment: and if you use single quote (use the `replace(char,char)`)

Comment: Have you tried putting the value attribute in double quotes instead of single quotes so it's consistent with the var attribute?

Comment: @ratchet freak, I just checked the API. I think you're right here. You should put your comment as an answer.

Comment: Unrelated to the concrete problem, why exactly do you need that information in a JSP? Whatever functional requirement you thought to solve with this approach, it has definitely to be solved differently.

Comment: You should look up StringEscapeUtils, and use the XML Encoder in there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439298/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml-in-java

Comment: @BalusC - I need it to access an XML file external to my .war file, located in tomcat/webapps to perform XSL transformation. Could you suggest some better way to do it?

Comment: What's the next bit of XML? I'm wondering whether you need to do anything about the backslashes at all. You usually don't.

Comment: @EJP - I updated my first post with the code where I'm using this variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about `"\\"` being a regular expression ... because that wouldn't result in a JSP compilation error.  (And besides, the argument of `String.replace(String)` isn't interpreted as a regex.)

However, the compilation error does seem to be saying that you need double escaping, and I *think* that the reason is that the JSP syntax is "consuming" one level of escaping itself ... in this context.

This is from the JSP 2.1 spec:

## JSP.1.6 Quoting and Escape Conventions

> ...

### Quoting in Attributes

> Quotation is done consistently regardless of whether the attribute value is a
>   literal or a request-time attribute expression. Quoting can be used in attribute
>   values regardless of whether they are delimited using single or double quotes. It is
>   only required as described below.
>
> - A `‘` is quoted as `\’`. This is required within a single quote-delimited attribute
>     value.
> - A `“` is quoted as `\”`. This is required within a double quote-delimited attribute
>     value.
> - A `\` is quoted as `\\`
> - Only when the EL is enabled for a page (see Section JSP.3.3.2, “Deactivating
>     EL Evaluation”), a literal `$` can be quoted by `\$`. Similarly, a literal `#` can be
>     quoted by `\#`. This is not required but is useful for quoting EL expressions.
> - A `%>` is quoted as `%\>`
> - A `<%` is quoted as `<\%`
> - The entities `&apos;` and `&quot;` are available to describe single and double
>     quotes.

---

Anyway, try writing the offending code fragment as `replace("\\\\", "/")`.

Comment: The // works because URL normalization rules treat // as meaning the same thing as / in path. You didn't need to double the forward-slash characters, but it is harmless in this use-case.