# How to do XML string replacement?

Tags: java, xml

I need to escape the XML string before transform into an XML file. I do it like this:

Java Code :

```
public static final String[][] XML_ENTITIES = {
    {"&","&amp;"},{">","&gt;"},{"<","&lt;","'","&apos;","\"","&quot;"}
};

public static String escape(String str){
    for(int i=0;i<XML_ENTITIES.length;i++){
        String name = XML_ENTITIES[i][0];
        String value = XML_ENTITIES[i][1];
        int idx = str.indexOf(name);
        if(idx > -1){
            str = str.replace(name, value);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

It works fine but it fails in some cases .

Example :

```
escape(">>,,a,a<<")
```

Output:

```
&gt;&gt;,,a,a&lt;&lt;
```

Failure Case:

```
escape("&amp;>,,a,a<<")
```

Output:

```
&amp;amp;&gt;,,a,a&lt;&lt;
```

If a xml string contains `&amp;` no need to escape the `&` character in the string . If I `unescape` the string and do escape it works fine . How can I do without unescaping?

Comment: have you seen `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()` ?

Comment: @user1516873 this is worth an answer.

Comment: Your second example looks correctly escaped to me.  If you want to handle partially-escaped strings, consider unescaping the string first, then applying the escape method to the unescaped string.

Comment: A duplicate of  [Best way to encode text data for XML in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439298/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml-in-java)
Not to mention reinventing the wheel,  nth time. Why do people think that embedding a string containing some special characters is something no one else int the whole universe has done ever before?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String[][] XML_ENTITIES = {
    {"&(?!amp;)","&amp;"},{">","&gt;"},{"<","&lt;","'","&apos;","\"","&quot;"}
};

public static String escape(String str){
    for(int i=0;i<XML_ENTITIES.length;i++){
        String name = XML_ENTITIES[i][0];
        String value = XML_ENTITIES[i][1];
        int idx = str.indexOf(name);
        if(idx > -1){
            str = str.replaceAll(name, value);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: use replaceAll and the regEx to match the &s not followed by amp;