# Regex to allow every character except invalid ones

Tags: java, xml, regex, special-characters

I have a problem that I want a regex pattern that allows every character, for example, alphabets , digits, special characters, umlaut characters but not invalid ones like an arrow sign which prevents me from generating a xml. Please help me with this and how can I replace that invalid character with a white space.?

I am using java 1.5

Comment: Disallowing invalid characters is usually a bad way to go. Replacing them with their entities seems much more reasonable (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439298/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml-in-java) for an answer on why/how).

Comment: Try looking at this answer & other answers listed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5008282/586621

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a `character class` and match all the valid characters

```
^[a-zA-Z\d]+$
```

But if you want dont want to allow certain characters you can use `Negated character class`

```
^[^><]+$
   --
    |->your arrow signs go here...
```

---

For example,`regex` like `[^a-zA-Z]` would match any character except a letter

Comment: How to avoid a symbol like a right arrow or left arrow or any such symbol '→', as we dont know what all these types of symbols can be, I just want to allow valid characters like alphanumeric , special characters etc.

Comment: @you can use `^[!-~\s]+$`..this will allow alpha-numeric and special characters..`!-~` means i am taking all characters within range `!` and `~`..refer to ascii chart for this...`\s` matches newline,space..etc..

Answer (score 0):

The `replaceAll` function will take a RegEx:

```
String myUnparsedString = "<some-xml-style-node>";
String myParsedString = myUnparsedString.replaceAll("<", " ");
```

Comment: i dont think thats what he's asking. he want to add text to xml, but the text has invalid xml chars that require escaping

Comment: Ah right… I read his question quickly, just thought he wanted something that would remove angle brackets so that the content could be put within XML tags; question could do with tidying TBH :)

Comment: i dunno now. maybe your answer is what he wants. I didn't realise that "arrow sign" might mean `<`.

Comment: My arrow sign is not made, it is like an arrow symbol in MS Word '→', theses type of symbols prevents me from creating xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do to remove all unwanted characters like arrow:

```
String cleanXML = xml.replaceAll("[^\u0000-\u00ff]+", " ");
```

Which is simply replacing 1 or more characters outside `\x00-\xFF` range with space.

Comment: This is working correct, But this is also removing chinese and arabic symbols!!

Comment: You didn't mention requirement of chinese and arabic symbols in your question.