# How to create custom emoji's in Java?

Tags: java, jsp, emoji, emoticons

I have a web based project using spring mvc outputting into jsp's. I want to be able to type `:)` and have it replaced with a picture of my trainers face. How would I do this? I can't find any questions on here that are either relevant nor guides on the Internet.

Thanks, 
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is convert user entered text into HTML, then replace the `:)` string with an image of your trainers face.

Note: It's **very** important to escape text when displaying it again as HTML, in order to prevent [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. Usually you use `<c:out>` to automatically do this escaping for you.

Since you want *some* HTML in the text, you can't use `<c:out>`, so *you* have to escape the rest of the text. See this page for ideas of how to do that: [Best way to encode text data for XML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439298/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml-in-java)

Then you replace the `:)` with an image tag: `<img src="trainer.png">`, and of course add that image file to your webapp.