# Java jcabi xpath returns unescaped text

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jcabi

Consider the following:

```
String s = "<tag>This has a &lt;a href=\"#\"&gt;link&lt;a&gt;.</tag>";
final XML xml = new XMLDocument(s);
String extractedText = xml.xpath("//tag/text()").get(0);
System.out.println(extractedText); // Output: This has a <a href="#">link</a>.
System.out.println(s.contains(extractedText)); // Output: false!
System.out.println(s.contains("This has a &lt;a href=\"#\"&gt;link&lt;a&gt;.")); // Output: true
```

I have an XML file given as a string with some escaped HTML. Using the jcabi library, I get the text of the relevant elements (in this case everything in `<tag>`s). However, what I get isn't actually what's in the original string--I'm expecting `&lt;` and `&gt;` but am getting `<` and `>` instead. The original string paradoxically does *not* contain the substring that I extracted from it.

How can I get the actual text and not an unescaped version?

Comment: Why do you expect the XML parser not to interpret entities like `&gt;`? Can you just [escape the string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/439494/223424) you receive from `.xpath()`?

Comment: @9000 I can't use the escape functions due to them escaping the quotes also (&quot;) and possibly a bunch of other things that don't match the source. Said source is out of my control and comes with some things escaped and some things unescaped. I need to do replacements on it so I need the extraction to be in the exact format that I got it in.

Comment: So, the source is in a non-canonical form, neither fully escaped nor fully unescaped. Bring it to the canonical form prior to doing anything with it. Stop considering it a text, for it's a serialized form of an XML document. Work with it as such, don't cling to the particular input form.