# regex to replace ambersands in php but not inside <script> tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a function like this:

```
function parser($buffer){
    $buffer = preg_replace('/&(?![#]?[a-z0-9]+;)/i', "&amp;$1", $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
```

What it does is replace all ampersands (the `&` symbol) in my output, with `&amp;` for xhtml validation purposes. The problem that i have is that ampersands inside `<script>` tags get converted too. Is there anyway i can ignore ampersands inside `<script>` tags so that they will not be converted? Is there any other way i could accomplish this?

Comment: what is it you are trying to do?  bigger picture?  convert php code into something else?  store it in a database?  can you give more context?

Answer (score 0):

```
$buffer = preg_replace("/((<[^>]*)|&)/e", '"\2"=="\1"? "\1":"&amp;"', $buffer);
```

Comment: add your (?![#]?[a-z0-9]+;) after the first &

Comment: did that user5715, but then nothing gets converted.`$buffer = preg_replace("/((<[^>]*)|&?![#]?[a-z0-9]+;)/e", '"\2"=="\1"? "\1":"&amp;"', $buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a lot of searching I found the answer:

```
    preg_replace('/&(?!(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*|#\d+);)(?!(?>(?:(?!<script|\/script>).)*)\/script>)/s', "&amp;$1", $text);
```

The regex is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462831/regular-expression-to-escape-html-ampersands-while-respecting-cdata) but with script tags instead of cdata. I thought I should post it since someone may find this little parser useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
&(?!(?<=(?<outerquote>["'])javascript:(?>(?!\k<outerquote>|[>]).)*)\k<outerquote>?)(?!(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*|#\d+);)(?!(?>(?:(?!<script|\/script>).)*)\/script>)
```

This will match the & only outside of script tags .. also it will ignore matches within anchors with javascript code in them.

Nice find "Samplist"... I needed it to work in JavaScript links as well like

```
<a href="javascript:alert('& & &');">Will correct this & but ignore those in the javascript:</a>
<script src="blaw.aspx?a=b&c=d" /><!-- want the Src to be corrected -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SomeFunction(){if (a=b) && (c=d){ IgnoreTheAmpsInIFWithinScript();}
</script>
&#123; is ignored but & is corrected
```