# Escaping new-line characters with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0, xmldocument

My application generates XML using XmlDocument.  Some of the data contains newline and carriage return characters.

When text is assigned to an XmlElement like this:

```
   e.InnerText = "Hello\nThere";
```

The resulting XML looks like this:

```
<e>Hello
There</e>
```

The receiver of the XML (which I have no control over) treats the new-line as white space and sees the above text as:

```
 "Hello There"
```

For the receiver to retain the new-line it requires the encoding to be:

```
<e>Hello&#xA;There</e>
```

If the data is applied to an XmlAttribute, the new-line is properly encoded.

I've tried applying text to XmlElement using InnerText and InnerXml but the output is the same for both.

Is there a way to get XmlElement text nodes to output new-lines and carriage-returns in their encoded forms?

Here is some sample code to demonstrate the problem:

```
string s = "return[\r] newline[\n] special[&<>\"']";
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.AppendChild( d.CreateXmlDeclaration( "1.0", null, null ) );
XmlElement  r = d.CreateElement( "root" );
d.AppendChild( r );
XmlElement  e = d.CreateElement( "normal" );
r.AppendChild( e );
XmlAttribute a = d.CreateAttribute( "attribute" );
e.Attributes.Append( a );
a.Value = s;
e.InnerText = s;
s = s
    .Replace( "&" , "&amp;"  )
    .Replace( "<" , "&lt;"   )
    .Replace( ">" , "&gt;"   )
    .Replace( "\"", "&quot;" )
    .Replace( "'" , "&apos;" )
    .Replace( "\r", "&#xD;"  )
    .Replace( "\n", "&#xA;"  )
;
e = d.CreateElement( "encoded" );
r.AppendChild( e );
a = d.CreateAttribute( "attribute" );
e.Attributes.Append( a );
a.InnerXml = s;
e.InnerXml = s;
d.Save( @"C:\Temp\XmlNewLineHandling.xml" );
```

The output of this program is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <normal attribute="return[&#xD;] newline[&#xA;] special[&amp;&lt;&gt;&quot;']">return[
] newline[
] special[&amp;&lt;&gt;"']</normal>
  <encoded attribute="return[&#xD;] newline[&#xA;] special[&amp;&lt;&gt;&quot;']">return[
] newline[
] special[&amp;&lt;&gt;"']</encoded>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.
Chris.

Comment: What you want is not clear. Please show what you want, and what you are getting

Comment: Look at the top 4 code lines: what I start with, what I'm getting, what the receiver sees, what I want.  Attributes encode newlines the way I want, Elements do not.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>How about using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx</strike>

OK, sorry about the wrong lead there. `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` will **not** handle the newline issue you're facing.

This blog link will help you out, though
http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2004/02/16/73675.aspx

Basically, the newline handling is controlled by the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute.

Sample working code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<ROOT/>");
doc.DocumentElement.InnerText = "1234\r\n5678";

XmlAttribute e = doc.CreateAttribute(
    "xml", 
    "space", 
    "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");
e.Value = "preserve";
doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append(e);

var child = doc.CreateElement("CHILD");
child.InnerText = "1234\r\n5678";
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(child);

Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output will read:

```
<ROOT xml:space="preserve">1234
5678<CHILD>1234
5678</CHILD></ROOT>
```

Comment: I've tested this and my receiver does not recognize or process the xml:space attribute.  The new-lines definitely have to be encoded as &#xA; or they are converted to white space.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is probably your best bet using the [methods described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157646/best-way-to-encode-text-data-for-xml). Or perhaps you could look at using a [CData section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection.aspx) for your content instead.

Comment: In my sample code above, there is a simple encoder.  The problem is getting XmlElement to preserve the encoded characters.  It keeps converting them back to new-line and carriage-return characters.

Answer (score 0):

In .net 2.0 use the XmlDocument [PreserveWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) switch

```
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

Comment: When I try this it has no effect on the encoding of new-line characters.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem 
[Preserve carriage returns when i write/read from xml file using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292407/preserve-carriage-returns-when-i-write-read-from-xml-file-using-asp-net)

the solution is to replace xml space to html space after html generated 
i add this

```
        strHtml = strHtml.Replace("&lt;br/&gt;", "<br/>");
```

at the end of the method before closing the stream reader