# Unescaping XML entities using XmlReader in .NET?

Tags: .net, xml, entities, translate

I'm trying to unescape XML entities in a string in .NET (C#), but I don't seem to get it to work correctly.

For example, if I have the string `AT&amp;T`, it should be translated to `AT&T`.

One way is to use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(), but that's for HTML.

So I have two questions about this:

1. Is it safe to use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() for decoding XML entities?
2. How do I use XmlReader (or something similar) to do this? I have tried the following, but that always returns an empty string:

   ```
   static string ReplaceEscapes(string text)
   {
       StringReader reader = new StringReader(text);

       XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

       settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

       using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
       {
           return xmlReader.ReadString();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your #2 solution can work, but you need to call `xmlReader.Read();` (or `xmlReader.MoveToContent();`) prior to `ReadString`.

I guess #1 would be also acceptable, even though there are those edge cases like `&reg;` which is a valid HTML entity, but not an XML entity – what should your unescaper do with it? Throw an exception as a proper XML parser, or just return “®” as the HTML parser would do?

Comment: Adding `xmlReader.MoveToContent()` did the trick, and that's exactly the solution I was looking for. I didn't really want to use HttpUtility because of the differences between HTML and XML, so your response was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 17):

HTML escaping and XML are closely related. as you have said, [`HttpUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e55w41w.aspx) has both [`HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) and [`HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) methods. These will also operate on XML, as there are only a few entities that need escaping: `<`,`>`,`\`,`'` and `&` in both HTML and XML.

The downside of using the `HttpUtility` class is that you need a reference to the `System.Web` dll, which also brings in a lot of other stuff that you probably don't want.

Specifically for XML, the [`SecurityElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt7ac8t7.aspx) class has an [`Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx) method that will do the encoding, but does not have a corresponding `Unescape` method. You therefore have a few options:

1. use the `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` and put up with a reference to `System.Web`
2. roll your own decode method that takes care of the special characters (as there are only a handful - look at the static constructor of `SecurityElement` in Reflector to see the full list)
3. use a (hacky) solution like:

.

```
    public static string Unescape(string text)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string xml = string.Format("<dummy>{0}</dummy>", text);
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        return doc.DocumentElement.InnerText;
    }
```

Personally, I would use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` if I already had a reference to `System.Web`, or roll my own if not. I don't like your `XmlReader` approach as it is `Disposable`, which usually indicate that it is using resources that need to be disposed, and so may be a costly operation.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
{
    if (xmlReader.Read())
    {
       return xmlReader.ReadString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the top answer has a small bug if your input text ends with certain white space characters, like carriage returns.

The string "Testing&#10;" loses it's trailing white space.

If you combine the solution in the question with adrianbanks' wrapper tag you get the following, which works.

```
public static string UnescapeUnicode(string line)
    {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader("<a>" + line + "</a>"))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
            {
                xmlReader.MoveToContent();
                return xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as well, and has least code:

```
    public static string DecodeString(string encodedString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formattedText))
            return string.Empty;
        XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(encodedString, XmlNodeType.Element, null);
        if (xtr.Read())
            return xtr.ReadString();
        throw new Exception("Error decoding xml string : " + encodedString);
    }
```

Update1: hmm, seems it does not work if encodeString is "", then xtr.Read() return false.

Update2: added workaround

Update3: this seem to work even better

```
    public static string DecodeString(string encodedString)
    {
        XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(encodedString, XmlNodeType.Element, null);
        xtr.MoveToContent();
        return xtr.Value;
    }
```